# peeker rewrite_html_transform_img_tags does not show full path

Tags: html, image

Do any one have experience on Peeker library for email fetching?
https://github.com/sophistry/peeker

I am using this library for fetching email and show in HTML page,

Everything works fine, but i could not render inline images in HTML,
With below code, my inline images are stored in local folder but in html link src is not getting complete,

```
$this->peeker->set_attachment_dir('./uploads/attachments/');
                    $email->save_all_attachments('./uploads/attachments/'); 
                    $email->rewrite_html_transform_img_tags($this->peeker->get_attachment_dir());
                    $newbody = $email->HTML_rewritten;
```

When i open HTML and inspect for element of picture, my source path is not seems completed,

See below,

```
<img height="177" width="284" apple-width="yes" apple-height="yes" apple-inline="yes" id="B13231B0-E5D8-49C8-9D89-52A3F8F039F0" src="./uploads/attachments/916207711e0253ebff5d3d24702718fc/images.jpeg" class="">
```

How can i show complete path of src="...

I can see images.jpeg in path .../uploads/attachments/images.jpeg,

Any advice for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself!,
Given base url in function,

```
$email->rewrite_html_transform_img_tags($base_url = 'http://localhost/testcenter/uploads/attachments');
```